# Exception in Application start method java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetExceptio

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

i am beginner in scene builder. This is my first code  and i get error please help me out.

> java

```
 package javaFXDemo;


    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.scene.Parent;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class Hello extends Application {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main1.fxml"));

            Scene scene = new Scene(root);

            primaryStage.setTitle("ok");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }
    }
```

> Fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="212.0" prefWidth="268.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171">
   <children>
      <Button layoutX="90.0" layoutY="94.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

> Error
>
> Exception in Application start method
>       java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
>         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
>       Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
>         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
>         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
>         at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
>         at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
>         at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
>         at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
>         at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
>         at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
>         at javaFXDemo.Hello.start(Hello.java:18)
>         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
>         at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
>         at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
>         at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
>         at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
>         at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
>         ... 1 more
>       Exception running application javaFXDemo.Hello

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required` is the key part of the error. Looks like your `getResource` is not working for `FXMLLoader.load`

Comment: Try using the full path: `getClass().getResource("/javaFXDemo/Main1.fxml")`; Also make sure the fxml file is included in the classpath at runtime.